# What is the coefficient of thermal expansion of real gases in terms of temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, heat-conduction

Is there an equation for the coefficient of thermal expansion of real gases. If there is, what is it then? because I tried to use [Peng Robinson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equations_of_state#Peng%E2%80%93Robinson_equation_of_state) of state, by substituting it's equation in terms of volume, I was getting into a mess.

Comment: Have you tried here: @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equation for the coefficient of thermal expansion of real gases.

If you have an expression for the volume $V$, you can use the definition of the thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$ as the relative increase in volume with increasing temperature $T$ at constant pressure $P$:

$$\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P.$$

If you have an expression for the entropy $S$, you can use a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations):

$$\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T.$$

If you have an energy potential such as the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy), you can relate that to the volume and proceed:

$$\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P\,\partial T}\right)=\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T\,\partial P}\right),$$

where the last term of course is the source of the Maxwell relation above, as $S\equiv-\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_P$.

If you have the [compressibility factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor) $Z=\frac{nRT}{PV}$, you can apply that:

$$\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{1}{T}\left[1+\frac{T}{Z}\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]=\frac{1}{T}\left[1+T\left(\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial T}\right)_P\right],$$

which is exactly the approach used in Pratt, "[Thermodynamic Properties Involving Derivatives Using the Peng-Robinson Equation of State](https://journals.flvc.org/cee/article/download/122983/121996)," *Chemical Engineering Education*, 35(2), 112-115 (2001), to find the thermal expansion coefficient for the Peng–Robinson gas (too intricate an expression to bother retyping).

Answer (score 2):

All equations of state (Van-der-Wall, clapeyron, the one you cited) are particular cases of the most general equation, the virial equation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_expansion (1)

Notice that there are an infinite number of gases, with different chemical properties. What you want, a general equation for all gases, is pratically impossible. You need to adjust the equations you know for each gas, comparing the set of parameters that best fit the behaviour of a real gas with the predict by (1)